# postgresql: full text search: how to understand ts_rank calculation

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am using postgresql 9.6. I am trying to understand ts_rank

I have a phrase "one two four" and my search query is 'one two three' So i am trying to get the ts_rank for all possible combinations as below.

```
select 
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('one')) AS one,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('two')) AS two,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('three')) AS three,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('one | two | three')) AS oneortwoorthree,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('one & two & three')) AS oneandtwoandthree,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('(one & two)')) AS mix2_1,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('(two & three)')) AS mix2_2,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('(one & three)')) AS mix2_3,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('(one & two) | three')) AS mix3_1,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('(two & three) | one')) AS mix3_2,
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('(one & three) | two')) AS mix3_3
```

I get the following results:

```
one: 0.0607927
two: 0.0607927
three: 0
oneortwoorthree: 0.0405285
oneandtwoandthree: 0.0991032
mix2_1: 0.0991032
mix2_2: 1e-20
mix2_3: 1e-20
mix3_1: 0.0405285
mix3_2: 0.0405285
mix3_3: 0.0405285
```

**Question 1:**
I am expecting

`ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('one & two & three')) AS oneandtwoandthree =` 0 Because one & two & three are not present.

**Question 2:**
How the rank for

```
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('one | two | three')) AS oneortwoorthree = 0.0405285
```

and

```
ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('(one & two) | three')) AS mix3_1, = 0.0405285
```

are same

**Question 3:**

I am expecting ts_rank for

`ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('one | two | three')) AS oneortwoorthree` = 0.0405285

should be greater than

`ts_rank(to_tsvector('one two four'), to_tsquery('one')) AS one` = 0.0607927

whereas it is inverse. There is high chances that any of the three words can exist in the phrase than a single word.